# Is it possible to create a 2D array where the row index is in a reverse order?

Tags: python, arrays

I am working on a simple game grid using a 2D array in Python. When the grid is printed I have set the first column of each row to display a row label but this has to be reversed to work ( 1 at the bottom of the grid- 5 at the top). Is there any way to create the array so when I insert a value at location [0][1] it appears at the bottom of the grid in the second column rather than at the top?

```
grid = [['' for x in range(1,6)] for x in range(1,6)]
# add the player pieces
grid[0][1]= 'P1'
grid[0][2]= 'P2'
grid[0][3]= 'P3'
grid[0][4]= 'P4'

label=['1-Start','2','3','4','5-Finish']
label.reverse()

i=0
for row in grid:
    print (label[i]," ".join(row))
    i+=1
```

I will use the row positions to work out game moves (up or down) later.
(Edit)
This is what it currently looks like- I would like the position of P1 etc. to be at the foot of the printed grid- is there a way of doing this? I can't upload images but this is what it prints out as:

```
5-Finish P1 P2 P3 P4
4
3
2
1-Start
```

I would like to know if I can create the array so that grid location [0][1] for the value'P1' would print out like this ( and I would not need to reverse my label list):

```
5-Finish 
4
3
2
1-Start P1 P2 P3 P4
```

Comment: can give expected output.

Comment: it is quite unclear to me what you exactly mean - could you provide some example grids of what your code produces, and what you want it to produce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1) First Method

You can use negative index to define your grid.
`grid[-1]` corresponds to the last cell.
In this case, use:

```
grid[-1][1]= 'P1'
grid[-1][2]= 'P2'
grid[-1][3]= 'P3'
grid[-1][4]= 'P4'
```

### 2) Second Method

There is another way to proceed; you can invert the list index this way `grid[::-1]`:

```
for row in grid[::-1]:
    print (label[i]," ".join(row))
    i+=1
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I've been messing about with a negative index but could not quite figure it out. I think I will probably use method 2 as this will make more sense later in my game.